# How do I link and embed a UTF8 encoded text file in an MS-Word document?

Tags: utf-8, ms-word, word-field

I would like to include the contents of a UTF8 text file in a MS Word document as a link.  This works for an ansi encoded file using the field:

`{INCLUDETEXT  "path\file.txt" \c ansitext  \* MERGEFORMAT}`

Is there a directive akin to `\c ansitext` for UTF8 files?  `\c utf8` and `\c utf8text` do not appear to work.

If I do not give any directive, Word recognizes that the file is UTF8, but a dialog pops up requiring me to confirm this each time the file needs updating, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Word's field codes are old, old technology, barely maintained and practically never updated. So no field switches for newer encoding, etc. that I'm aware of. Indeed, the current documentation for the field does not even list the one you use. The "confirm" message can, I believe, be deactivated from File/Options, the Advanced tab, but I'm currently on a mobile device and can't test/confirm. It's also possible to ***lock*** the field so that it won't update (unlock specifically in order to update, then lock again).

Comment: «Word's field codes are old, old technology, barely maintained and practically never updated.» They may be old, but they *are* maintained & updated. Just think of the additions of \b & \f switches to mergefields, the creation of CITATION & BIBLIOGRAPHY fields, etc.

Comment: @adr Have you tried omitting the switches? You certainly don't need the \\* MERGEFORMAT switch.

Comment: Wow, I was afraid there would be no response.  @CindyMeister, the confirm on open option has no effect.

Comment: @slightly snarky, I am not sure I want that behaviour, also I am still using word 2010.

Comment: @macropod, "maintained & updated" is great, but documented?  I do need the mergeformat to keep the font size I want.

Comment: The AnsiText option was one Word put in itself at some point.  Meanwhile I stumbled upon a patent text(!) which reads: "For example, Microsoft Word version 2000 is able to open HTML, MSRTF, AnsiText, PCText, AnsiTextCR, Unicode, EncodedText and PctextCR format files."

Comment: But the prompt appear to be triggered by the simple presence of higher order bytes in the file pretty much independent of which option I choose.  Even adding a BOM to the file didn't help.

Comment: I'll live with the prompts for this project and take another approach for the next.  Thanks all!

Comment: «"maintained & updated" is great, but documented?» I already gave document examples. «I do need the mergeformat to keep the font size I want» You're misusing the \* MERGEFORMAT switch for that, since plain text files have no font name or size. Moreover, if you add text to the linked text file, you're liable to find the \* MERGEFORMAT switch no longer formats all the text. You should use a \* CHARFORMAT switch instead. See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-field-results-baa61f5a-5636-4f11-ab4f-6c36ae43508c

Comment: I wanted to apply a style to the included text, but for some reason that wasn't easy.  It would only stick if I applied it in stages to parts of the included text and used the MERGFORMAT.  The CHARFORMAT does work better.

Comment: I think the question is answerable. What I want is not possible because of various Word details.  I could post this answer with explanations, but will delay in case one of you wants to do it.

Comment: Are any of these comments needed any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *is* a directive ( \c Unicode ) but unfortunately using it does not actually eliminate the character encoding pop-up, even when the Unicode text starts with a BOM (Byte Order Mark), which are in any case discouraged by Unicode.

So although that answers the question actually asked, it doesn't solve the problem. Nor, according to the discussion in comments to the Question, would any of the following solve the problem for the OP, but they might help others.

According to the ISO 29500 standard that describes .docx documents, INCLUDETEXT is supposed to have an \e switch that lets you specify an encoding. But, according to Microsoft's standard document [MS-OI29500].pdf, Word ignores any \e switch.

As far as I am aware the only way to avoid that pop-up when the included text is in Unicode format (UTF-8) is to set a value in the Windows Registry that tells Word the default encoding for text files.

The problem with that is that that setting will affect what happens to all the text files opened by Word, whether through the file open dialog or an INCLUDETEXT.

To create the setting, you need to navigate to the following Registry location, e.g. for Word 2016/2019 it would be

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options
```

and for Word 2010 it would be

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Options
```

Then add a DWORD value called `DefaultCPG` and set its value to the code page you want to be the default. For UTF-8, that's decimal 65001.

If you have control over the format of the file to be included, you could consider using a format that wouldn't trigger the encoding pop-up. That leads to another set of problems, e.g. if you used HTML you would probably have to deal with HTML special characters such as & etc., whitespace, and RTL characters (which Word seems to reverse). But the following HTML "framework" is enough to insert a text chunk without additional paragraph marks and so on:

```
<html>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <body>
    <a name="x">your text</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the INCLUDETEXT field, you then use the "x" to indicate the subset you want to include, e.g.

```
{INCLUDETEXT  "path\file.htm" x \c HTML}
```

The HTML coding `<a name="something">` is deprecated in HTML 5, but Word only understands the earlier HTML convention.